# Should I beat my Creature for pooing on my Temple?

Tags: black-and-white

My Creature occasionally poos on my Temple. It this worth punishing?

The first time I saw it do this I was a bit offended and strongly discouraged it with a few slaps. Now that I'm busier on Land 1 though, I don't have as much time for training and I let it slide a few times. It only seems to think pooing on the Temple is a good idea just after waking up in its pen and eating; otherwise it's pretty well trained to use trees and bushes, so it's not part of a bigger potty-training problem.

Is letting it poo on my Temple going to have any adverse effects? I'm pretty sure that the pen part of the Temple is distinct from the Worship Site parts of the Temple, so I'm not worried about him getting bigger and bombing my worshippers while they're "at church", I'm just worried that there are hidden belief/idea effects that will bite me later. Will villagers disrespect me as a god worth taking seriously? Does my Creature think this is as disrespectful as I do, or is that just not a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creature poop in the pen won't have negative effects. If it gets in the worship sites, it might- there is a stat for how beautiful the worship site based on trees and decoration in it which can cause worshipers to hide instead of worshipping- poop may reduce that.

Other than that, poop doesn't hurt villagers unless you actually drop it on them. Or set it on fire and throw it at their houses...

Comment: New personal win condition: teach my monkey to throw flaming poo at enemy villages.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie just remember not to pet him while he's holding the flaming poo.

Comment: I'm sure that's not a choice he'd make twice…